# Gramatically understand "make more and more of an impression on.."

Tags: meaning, grammar, idioms

The case I want to understand is "Japanese musician YOSHIKI is making more and more of an impression on the British royal family". As I understand it, it says YOSHIKI is impressing the British royal family members more and more. But what I don't understand is the grammar detail.

Is "making more and more of an impression" the comparative of "making much of an impression"? In that case, how should I understand "making much of an impression"? Is it a combination of "making an impression" and "much of", or alternatively, a combination of "making much of" and "an impression"?

From what I learnt from the internet, ["much of"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/more-less-much-of-a-something) is "used for describing the importance of a quality that something has" and ["make much of"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-much-of-sth) means "to give a lot of importance to something". I can't see anyone is giving an importance on the thing of impressing some one else. Thenceforth, I prefer the "making an impression" + "much of" assumption. But I still can't understand it. What does the "much of" mean here? I can understand what ["not much of a"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/not%20much%20of%20a) means but what "much of" means is still unclear. What does it actually mean in this context?

Glad you can bear the reading. Love you :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers) explains that

> When we use ***much*** or ***many*** before articles **(a/an, the)**, demonstratives (this, that), possessives (my, your) or pronouns (him, them), *we need to use **of***.

There is the set phrase is *more​/​less​/​much of **a** something*, and as you can see, it can be combined with comparatives:

> used for describing the importance of a quality that something has
>
> - It was really ***more of a*** comment than a question. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/more-less-much-of-a-something))

As for your example, it is a combination of the phrase ***[more and more](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/more-less-much-of-a-something)*** and the set phrase I just explained, to show that the impression made does not cease  to increase.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense quite much.